# Duplicate joins or use a subquery?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I have a query like this (please ignore some mistakes in it as the query has been changed and simplified to hide some info):

```
SELECT 
-- Some columns

(case when Benefit.Type = 0 then Benefit.HS end) as HSF,
(case when Benefit.Type = 1 then Benefit.HS end) as HSR,
(case when Benefit.Type = 0 then Benefit.VS end) as VSF,
(case when Benefit.Type = 1 then Benefit.VS end) as VSR,
(case when Benefit.Type = 0 then Benefit.SS end) as SSF,
(case when Benefit.Type = 1 then Benefit.SS end) as SSR,

(case when Benefit.Type = 0 then Benefit.HS + Benefit.VS + Benefit.SS end) as BF,
(case when Benefit.Type = 1 then Benefit.HS + Benefit.VS + Benefit.SS end) as BR

FROM 
Project
left join BC on BC.Project_Id = Project.Id
left join (select Seq, BC.Type,
    SUM(case PT.Name
        when 'Ch' then
            case Benefit.Analysis 
                when 2 then IBenefit.VHS * 12
                when 1 then IBenefit.VHS end
        else IBenefit.VHS end) HS,
    SUM(case PT.Name
        when 'Ch' then
            case Benefit.Analysis 
                when 2 then IBenefit.VVS * 12
                when 1 then IBenefit.VVS end
        else IBenefit.VVS end) VS,
    SUM(case PT.Name
        when 'Ch' then
            case Benefit.Analysis 
                when 2 then IBenefit.VSS * 12
                when 1 then IBenefit.VSS end
        else IBenefit.VSS end) SS

from Project 
left join BC on BC.Project_Id = Project.Id
left join Benefit on Benefit.BC_Id = BC.Id
left join IBenefit on IBenefit.Benefit_Id = Benefit.Id
group by Project.Seq, BC.Type) as Benefit on Benefit.Seq = Project.Seq
-- Some more JOINs like this
```

Basically this query takes the data from a many to many relation (between Project, BC, Benefit and IBenefit) and summarize in the subquery so the calculations doesn't have to repeat (I mean the code in the select statement (`case when Benefit.Type = ....`).

I'm wondering if this is really the best approach or if I should select all the necessary info (even creating several rows for the same project) and group them using a query outside (`SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...) AS QUERY`).

Not sure if my description is clear, so if you have any question feel free to ask me.

### UPDATE

Expected output:

```
+---------+---------+--------+---------+--------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| Project |   HSF   |  HSR   |   VSF   |  VSR   |  SSF   |   SSR   |   BF   |   BR    |
+---------+---------+--------+---------+--------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| A       |    3432 | 324234 |  876898 | 987987 | 987987 | 9879879 | 987987 | 9879879 |
| B       | 8765865 | 675875 | 9758975 |   9859 |     85 |  985985 | 985985 |     985 |
| C       |   87687 |   7687 |  687687 | 876876 | 876876 |  876087 | 987986 |    9869 |
+---------+---------+--------+---------+--------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```

But the data without calculation/aggregation is like this:

```
+---------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Project | BCType | BenefitHS | BenefitVS | BenefitSS | BenefitAnalysis | IBenefitVHS | IBenefitVSS | IBenefitVVS |
+---------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| A       |      0 |         3 |         2 |         6 |               5 |           5 |           7 |           6 |
| A       |      1 |         3 |         7 |         7 |              76 |          68 |           8 |           6 |
| B       |      0 |         3 |         7 |         7 |               8 |           7 |           9 |           3 |
| C       |      0 |         2 |         6 |        98 |               5 |          97 |           6 |           5 |
| C       |      1 |         6 |         8 |         5 |               0 |           5 |           9 |           7 |
+---------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

These are fake values just to show the summarization idea.

If I don't use this subquery, my main query would be like this:

```
    SELECT 
    -- Some columns

    (case when Benefit.Type = 0 then 
SUM(case PT.Name
            when 'Ch' then
                case Benefit.Analysis 
                    when 2 then IBenefit.VHS * 12
                    when 1 then IBenefit.VHS end
            else IBenefit.VHS end) end) as HSF,
    (case when Benefit.Type = 1 then 
SUM(case PT.Name
            when 'Ch' then
                case Benefit.Analysis 
                    when 2 then IBenefit.VHS * 12
                    when 1 then IBenefit.VHS end
            else IBenefit.VHS end) end) as HSR,
    (case when Benefit.Type = 0 then 
SUM(case PT.Name
            when 'Ch' then
                case Benefit.Analysis 
                    when 2 then IBenefit.VVS * 12
                    when 1 then IBenefit.VVS end
            else IBenefit.VVS end) end) as VSF,
    (case when Benefit.Type = 1 then 
SUM(case PT.Name
            when 'Ch' then
                case Benefit.Analysis 
                    when 2 then IBenefit.VVS * 12
                    when 1 then IBenefit.VVS end
            else IBenefit.VVS end) end) as VSR,
    (case when Benefit.Type = 0 then 
SUM(case PT.Name
            when 'Ch' then
                case Benefit.Analysis 
                    when 2 then IBenefit.VSS * 12
                    when 1 then IBenefit.VSS end
            else IBenefit.VSS end) end) as SSF,
    (case when Benefit.Type = 1 then 
SUM(case PT.Name
            when 'Ch' then
                case Benefit.Analysis 
                    when 2 then IBenefit.VSS * 12
                    when 1 then IBenefit.VSS end
            else IBenefit.VSS end) end) as SSR,

    (case when Benefit.Type = 0 then Benefit.HS + SUM(case PT.Name
            when 'Ch' then
                case Benefit.Analysis 
                    when 2 then IBenefit.VVS * 12
                    when 1 then IBenefit.VVS end
            else IBenefit.VVS end) + SUM(case PT.Name
            when 'Ch' then
                case Benefit.Analysis 
                    when 2 then IBenefit.VSS * 12
                    when 1 then IBenefit.VSS end
            else IBenefit.VSS end) end) as BF,
    (case when Benefit.Type = 1 then Benefit.HS + SUM(case PT.Name
            when 'Ch' then
                case Benefit.Analysis 
                    when 2 then IBenefit.VVS * 12
                    when 1 then IBenefit.VVS end
            else IBenefit.VVS end) + SUM(case PT.Name
            when 'Ch' then
                case Benefit.Analysis 
                    when 2 then IBenefit.VSS * 12
                    when 1 then IBenefit.VSS end
            else IBenefit.VSS end) end) as BR

    FROM 
    Project
    left join BC on BC.Project_Id = Project.Id
    left join Benefit on Benefit.BC_Id = BC.Id
    left join IBenefit on IBenefit.Benefit_Id = Benefit.Id
    -- Some more JOINs like this
```

Comment: the best approach depends on many factors. in the question are missing many key elements helpful to give advice: data example, expected result example, hints about indexes.

Comment: In order to check query performance you can profile it. In any case using of nested SQL is not a best practice. Better first select data to in memory table (or temp table), then group data from this table.

Comment: Update the question to include the expected result. The question is more about duplicating or not a table that`s already in the FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is, you have similar tables in subquery and main query. So instead of using subquery, you can do the calculation/aggregation part in the main query itself. It will reduce the number of times sql server query optimizer has to hit the same tables to fetch data. Also, it will make your code more readable and easy to understand.

Note: It is just based on observation, best way would really depend upon the expected results and expected performance.

Comment: That's exactly the point. I'm thinking on placing these calculations in the main query, however, this will require to repeat the CASE WHEN logic.